# Google Analytics only showing my local visits

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I set up google analytics on my 'coming soon' website about 4 days ago but the dashboard's only showing my local visits. I know for certain that there have been visits to the website after analytics was set-up because I've gotten a number of email signups. Here is the ga code snippet i added within the head tag of my html.

```
<script>
      (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
      (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
      m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
      })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

      ga('create', 'UA-Removed-my-ga-account-id', 'auto');
      ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

Comment: Have you used any filters in the gA view?

Comment: No filters used